# Is there something to see outside the normal analog TV video frame?

Tags: tv

I've heard from TV repairmen and read in various sources through the years  that the TV radio signal isn't shown on radio TVs in its entirety. I've noticed that on different radio TVs the same channel looks cropped differently. Some show more, some less. The displayed picture is apparently cropped to avoid showing the outside regions which carry no useful to the viewer graphics (possibly noise or just black border). I've also learned that it might contain something else which could be interesting to an enthusiast. I couldn't find much by googling different variations of my question, but it seems like there may be some lines and shapes which help with auto-tuning the frequency to make the picture straight and crisp. But I could be wrong.

Is there something outside the image frame that we normally see on TVs? If so, what does the full image look like? Does it vary between countries or radio broadcasting standards? I'd like to see a collection of different screencaps with annotations for what's what.

The format here seems to be SECAM D/K.

Comment: It will probably matter what analog TV format is (or was) used where you live. PAL or NTSC or SECAM (or something more obscure)?

Comment: Teletext was stored in the extra lines.

Comment: An analog TV (I assume you are talking about these) has its own electronics design, display tube physics, as well as various control knobs for adjusting analog parameters. Broadcast standards provide for a certain number of lines, each line composed of an analog varying signal, all of this composed into frames. Your TV electronics attempts to map that onto its display tube. How well all this works depends on the receiving hardware and electronics and transmitter to receiver section vagaries. So sure. It varies. The broadcast image is almost always better. Some lines also reserved for features.

Comment: The format is most likely SECAM D/K, the question is about analog TVs, and  I remember having Teletext on one of them.

Comment: There can be test wave patterns , and data in the VBI. We once used one line with data for streaming games in the early 80's with our 4Mbps modem and serial port.

Comment: "TV repairmen" I thought they went the way of the Dodo...

Comment: Perhaps the bigger question should be is there ANYTHING useful to see / watch in the picture part of the TV... LOL

Answer (score 6):

In the analog days, there was often digital information transmitted in the top few lines of the picture. This could be quite visible on some channels and if you looked closely you could make out digital counters incrementing away.

Others used the blanking side bands for information which was not visible on the screen.

These methods were used to transmit information for various purposes including text based services [Teletext](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teletext), e.g  CEEFAX etc,. also  to pass along information to sub-broadcasters to allow them to insert local advertisements etc, as well as closed captioning.

However, most of this fell by the wayside with the advent of digital television where information has other methods to use that do not steal from the picture bandwidth.

Also, for NTSC analog color TV signals there is a [colorburst](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorburst) signal that is transmitted at the start of each line. This signal synchronizes your TV to permit it to know which part of the signal that follows is intended for each color "gun". Again, this part of the signal is normally blanked out by your TV.

However, ultimately, it depends on the standard used in your locale and the station and carrier company.

Answer (score 2):

The noise in the extra lines is data. In many countres that data was made readable  for the ordinary watchers . People had text tv mode in their receivers. There was info about programs, news and extra subtitles for minority folks. There also could be advertisements.

Answer (score 1):

Analog TV standards had to compensate for tolerances and drift in the beam deflection circuits of tube TV sets. Thus, the transmitted picture was not meant to be completely displayed on the screen. TV sets were designed and adjusted to place the edges of the transmitted image slightly beyond the edges of the screen. This made sure that no black borders would appear on screen if the beam deflection decreased due to temperature or component drift.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_area_(television)

Comment: I know that already and this doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @user1306322, verbocity of your question leads to a different conclusion, since you didn't mention any sources that you bothered to study.